# Unity - wait until animation finished

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to start a co-routine after my animation finished playing.

I tried it like this:

```
...

while (animCamera.isPlaying) {
    new WaitForSeconds(1);
}

StartCoroutine(LoadAsync(sceneName, sliderLoadbar, sliderLoadbarText));
```

But this crashes my unity and even my browser after a while and my unity stucks as soon as the while loop is entered.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The syntax is `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1)` ;

Comment: But you may be interested by : `yield return new WaitUntil(() => animCamera.isPlaying);` Or by [State Machine Behaviour](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours)

Comment: Nice, that looks promising, but my attempt failed. Unity does not freeze or crash anymore, but nothing happens and the game is stucked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the animation tab of your animated gameobject create an event at the last frame of the animation, attach the above script to this gameobject, and choose the method you want to run at the end of it

[image]

Remove The coroutine and just make a simple method

```
public void LoadScene()
{
   LoadAsync(sceneName, sliderLoadbar, sliderLoadbarText)
}
```